# Type checking errors in Swift

Tags: macos, swift4

```
func cal(X: [Int], Y: [Int64]) -> Double {
    let total = Double(Y.reduce(0, +))
    var z = zip(X, Y).map { pow(Double($0), 2) * Double($1) }.reduce(0, +) / Double(total)
    return z
}
```

I am getting this error

> Cannot capture 'Double' before it is declared
>   Use of local variable 'Double' before its declaration

How to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. This code seems to compile fine. I suspect your problem is elsewhere or that this isn't your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem, but you've written this is a fairly awkward way IMO. You want everything to be Double, so just make it Double, and then the code gets much simpler and you don't need all the casting. `pow(x,2)` is also a very expensive way to compute `x*x`, so I would get rid of that, and I think the code gets much simpler, and definitely does not have any problem compiling.

```
func cal(xs: [Int], ys: [Int64]) -> Double {
    let xs = xs.lazy.map(Double.init)
    let ys = ys.lazy.map(Double.init)

    let total = ys.reduce(0, +)
    return zip(xs, ys).map { $0*$0 * $1 }.reduce(0, +) / total
}
```

If you're doing a lot of this kind of code, you may find the `sum()` extension helpful to make the code a little clearer.

```
extension Sequence where Element: Numeric {
    func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(0, +)
    }
}

func cal(xs: [Int], ys: [Int64]) -> Double {
    let xs = xs.lazy.map(Double.init)
    let ys = ys.lazy.map(Double.init)

    let total = ys.sum()
    return zip(xs, ys).map { $0*$0 * $1 }.sum() / total
}
```